# get all records matching the query string and display like in google suggest by google

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models

What I want to do is, somewhat similar to google suggest.
My client page will submit the search text through ajax to server. The server will grab that text and query all the records matching that string and return back to client page.

**e.g.**
text_frm_client = "Ba". The query will show all the records beginning with "Ba"

---

The raw sql query to achieve my problem is

```
    **Select * from table_name where column1 LIKE "Ba%" or column2 LIKE "Ba%"**
```

---

Now I want to port this query to django model. What I found is somewhat somewhat similar.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains

But this is only for one field. How can I accomplish the sql query with django model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Q`

```
data = MyModel.objects.filter(
        Q(column1__contains="Ba") | 
        Q(column2__contains="Ba")
        )
```

Comment: @catherine.....yes that worked..

need to import
`from django.db.models import Q`

...Thanks.. :)